# how to clear value after form submit success "token-field" data in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have try to clear value:

```
<input type="text" class="token-field" name="meta_keyword" id="meta_keyword" value="">

$('#meta_keyword').val();
```

but it's not working.

Comment: `$('#meta_keyword').val('');` will set your input value to nothing (ie: clear it)

Comment: @NiravSutariya [it works for me](https://jsfiddle.net/6s0ybm9v/) ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this code.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "url",
    type: "POST",
    success: function(obj)
    {
        $("#meta_keyword").tokenfield('setTokens', []);
    }
});
```